# How to search and replace any digit at beginning of an MS Word paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

Trying to do a find a replace on any paragraph that begins with a number.

Tried this in Find and Replace:

```
Find what:
(^13)(^#)
```

But get the error

> ^# is not a valid special character for the find what box or is not
>   supported when the Use Wildcards check box is selected.

**Update:**
Forgot to mention that my Use Wildcards box is checked in the search options. I am attempting to replace styles based on paragraphs that start with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not clear whether you’re trying to do a Microsoft Word “Find and Replace”,
or whether you’re trying to use the Find function to find paragraphs that begin with numbers,
so you can then edit them manually. 
If it’s the latter, why not just turn off “Use wildcards” and search for `^p^#` or `^13^#`?

Comment: Turning off wildcards did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try <[0-9]{1,} for checking for numbers.  if you know there is an upper limit to the number of characters the numbers will be you can change it to {1,4} for example and it will search for any number between 0 and 9999 including 0000.

That will check the beginning of words for one or more numeric characters